# XML Markup Error

Tags: android, xml

**What I've done**

---

Hello Guys, I'm trying to create a custom ListView layout. I've already done this, but I get some XML Markup Errors:
*Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
     formed.
    - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element*

**Question**

---

Like this on how must my custom ListView layout look like that I don't get those errors? Down here you find the Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="No filter set"
    </TextView>
```

Thx in advance for your anwsers!
Best Regards

safari

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check all the comments that i have included in the below XML layout so that you will get better idea what you are missing and what you should include.

Your Layout should be like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <!-- Root layout view should be there to include other 2 or more than 2 views -->

    <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   <!-- Android schema must be there in root layout --> 

       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">    

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="No filter set">    <!-- You have missed to close the TextView tag ">" -->
        </TextView>
    </ListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` for your root element.(before you actually use `android:someAttributeHere`)

edit:You must have a top element(a layout or `<include />` tag that will wrap your two layouts elements) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="No filter set"
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where do I have to declare this, because when i put this in my ListView or TextView I still get a error

Answer (score 1):

You should add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and have a `ViewGroup` in your xml, containing these two views.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to declare

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

in your list view.